# R base function 'list.files()' returns empty result on the openCPU in some specific folder paths

Tags: r, opencpu

I tried 'list.files()' function on openCPU test page (/ocpu/test) with

- Endpoint: /ocpu/library/base/R/list.files/json
- Param Name : path
- Param Value : '/home/dykim22'

then it returned correct list of files of my home folder. Yes it works.

However, when I try with different folder '/DATA/test' it returns empty.

Modes and owner of those two folders are the same.

- /home/dykim22 : drwxr-xr-x 24 dykim22 dykim22
- /DATA/test    : drwxr-xr-x  2 dykim22 dykim22

Are there anyone can explain this?
Thanks.

Comment: You would need to add that directory to the security profile. See section 3.5 of the [manual](http://jeroenooms.github.com/opencpu-manual/opencpu-server.pdf).

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks Jroen! Monitoring the kern.log gives a clear sight of the problem :)